# Is there a way to make typescript generics props not read only ?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am newbie in React and Typescript.In AlertDismissable class I am setting property of show when a request completed.I have used this sample and changed it a bit.

Depending on response I change AlertDismissable's contents and style.

When a user clicks hide button I am trying to set its show property to false.I have bound states with properties that's why I am trying to set props.However,compiler throws

TS2540: Cannot assign to 'show' because it is a constant or a read-only property.(handleDismiss method)

It seems generic props are read-only by default.Is there any other way to make it work ?

Here is my AlertDismissable tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Alert, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
interface AlertDismissableState {
    show: boolean;
    style: string;
}
export default class AlertDismissable extends React.Component<AlertDismissableState, AlertDismissableState> {

    constructor(props: any, context: any) {
        super(props, context);

        this.handleDismiss = this.handleDismiss.bind(this);
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            show: this.props.show,
            style: this.props.style
        };

    }
        handleDismiss() {
 this.props.show=false;        
}

    handleShow() {
        this.props.show=true;
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.show && this.props.style == "Success") {
            return (
                <Alert bsStyle="success">
                    <p>
                        Ok
                    </p>
        <Button onClick={this.handleDismiss}>Hide Alert</Button>

                </Alert>
            );
        }
        if (this.props.show && this.props.style == "Danger") {
            return (
                <Alert bsStyle="danger"> 
                    <p>
                        Failed
                    </p>
        <Button onClick={this.handleDismiss}>Hide Alert</Button>

                </Alert>
            );
        }
        return (<div />);
    }
}
```

Here is my component that includes AlertDismissable class.I removed some codes for brevitiy.

```
export default class UploadContainer extends React.Component<{}, UploadContainerState> {
uploadFile(event: any) {
        fetch("ProposalData/UploadFile", {
...
        })
            .then(handleErrors)
            .then(function (response) {
                that.setState({ alertVisible: true, style: "Success" });
            }).catch(function (error) {
                that.setState({ alertVisible: true, style: "Danger" });            });
}

render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <AlertDismissable show={this.state.alertVisible} style={this.state.style} />
</div>)}
```

typescript:2.9.1

react: "^16.4.0"

react-bootstrap: "^0.32.1"

react-dom: "^16.4.0",

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question. I will be answering a different one but the answer is the following:

In React you should **never** try to change `props`. Properties are what is being passed from the parent component. If you want to change properties, you have to go to the parent component and change what is being passed to `AlertDismissable`.

Actually, you should pass a property `onDismiss` of type function to `AlertDismissable` and call `this.props.onDismiss()` instead of `this.props.show = false`. Then you need to change the `state` of `UploadContainer` in that function.

Also note that your `AlertDismissable` class does not need to maintain `state` at all and it should use `props` directly.

I am not a typescript developer myself but it should be something like this:

```
interface AlertDismissableState {
  show: boolean;
  style: string;
  onDismiss: () => void;
}
```

and then just:

```
<Button onClick={this.props.onDismiss}>
  Hide Alert
</Button>
```

and in the parent component:

```
<AlertDismissable
  show={this.state.alertVisible}
  style={this.state.style}
  onDismiss={() => this.setState({ alertVisible: false })}
/>
```

By the way, it does not make much sense to render `AlertDismissable` component when it should be hidden. You could consider:

```
{this.state.alertVisible && (
  <AlertDismissable
     style={this.state.style}
     onDismiss={() => this.setState({ alertVisible: false })}
  />
)}
```

instead of passing the flag and render an empty `<div/>`.

Comment: Note for users who will try to implement this example or similar pattern.

OnDismiss must be defined as following.
interface AlertDismissableState {
    onDismiss?: () => void;
}
If it is defined as function it gives following error.
Types of property 'onClick' are incompatible.
      Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'EventHandler<MouseEvent<Button>> | undefined'.

Comment: @erhan355 Updated, as I said, I am only a JS developer and I don't know typescript :)

Comment: yes I know, many thanks for your nice answer.I added comment for other users to fully benefit from answer.;)